# Android Facebook - Login / Logout Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-facebook

I've managed to successfully implement Facebook login into my Android app.The issue I'm facing is,on my logout,whenever I click the logout button,I would like to capture the click of "Cancel / Logout" options.How do I go about doing this?Below are images attached for a much clearer illustration.

[image: Logout Page]

[image]

As shown in the images,how do I go about capturing the clicks in the highlighted red circles?
Below attached are my codes for the login/logout activity as well.Thank you :)

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    // Get more permissions
    authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays
            .asList("publish_actions,read_stream"));
    authButton.setFragment(getParentFragment());
```

Answer (score 0):

I now this post is very old but...

I had the same problem as you, what I did was:
(only sure for facebook sdk v2.0)

1. Go to package com.facebook.widget;

2. Open the file **LoginButton.java**;

3. Go to line 819 inside the **public void onClick(View v)**;
4. See the allert Dialog? I just comented the code as follows:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage(message)
                       .setCancelable(true)
                       .setPositiveButton(logout, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               openSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                           }
                       });
                       /*.setNegativeButton(cancel, null);*/
                builder.create().show();
```

And it is done!, no more annoying cancel button on dialog.
(You can also remove the whole dialog)

Comment: how did you comment that or modified that code??In andriod studio it is showing read only access for file..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and searched some many answers,but they doesnot work,so I just write some new codes in LoginButton.java in facebook sdk,my frist step:

```
public interface LogoutListener{
    public void afterLogin();
}

private LogoutListener mLoginoutListener;

public void setLogoutListener(LogoutListener loginoutListener){
    this.mLoginoutListener = loginoutListener;
}
```

second step:find 811 lines in LoginButton.java and you will see the code just like this:

```
private class LoginClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = getContext();
        final Session openSession = sessionTracker.getOpenSession();

        if (openSession != null) {
            // If the Session is currently open, it must mean we need to log out
            if (confirmLogout) {
                // Create a confirmation dialog
                String logout = getResources().getString(R.string.com_facebook_loginview_log_out_action);
                String cancel = getResources().getString(R.string.com_facebook_loginview_cancel_action);
                String message;
                if (user != null && user.getName() != null) {
                    message = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_as), user.getName());
                } else {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook);
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage(message)
                       .setCancelable(true)
                       .setPositiveButton(logout, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               openSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

                               // here is what I added
                               if(mLoginoutListener != null){
                                   mLoginoutListener.afterLogin();
                               }


                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton(cancel, null);
                builder.create().show();
            } else {
                openSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }
```

third step,and this is how I use :

```
LoginButton floginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.flogin_button);
        floginButton.setLogoutListener(new LogoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void afterLogin() {
                // do what you want ,when user click the "OK" button.

            }
        });
```

I changed a little bit codes in facebook sdk,and it worked for me,I hope this can help you.

Comment: how did you comment that or modified that code??In andriod studio it is showing read only access for file

Comment: @River please tell me the steps for making changes in Facebook sdk Login button